# Why do I get "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('" when I run my Perl one-liner?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

This is driving me insane.  Here's my dilemma, I have a file in which I need to make a match.  Usually I use Perl and it works like a charm but in this case I am writing a shell script and for some reason it is throwing errors.

Here is what I am trying to match:

```
loop_loopStorage_rev='latest.integration'
```

I need to match `loop` and `latest.integration`.

This is my regex:

```
^(?!\#)(loop_.+rev).*[\'|\"](.*)[\'|\"]$
```

When I use this in a Perl script, `$1` and `$2` give me the appropriate output. If I do this:

```
perl -nle "print qq{$1 => $2} while /^(?!#)(loop_.+rev).+?[\'|\"](.+?)[\'|\"]$/g" non-hadoop.env
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I believe it has something to do with the beginning part of my regex. So my real question is would there be an easier solution using sed, egrep or awk? If so, does any one know where to begin?

Comment: "It throws an error"? What error?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that part, -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: You have double quotes around your whole expression, but also within it (which is messing it up).

Comment: I copied the wrong text, gah.  This is the correct thing I am running ---  `perl -nle "print qq{$1 => $2} while /^(?!#)(loop_.+rev).+?[\'|\"](.+?)[\'|\"]$/g" non-hadoop.env`

Comment: Note: `(?!\#)(loop_.+rev)` is the same as `(loop_.+rev)` (since `l` isn't `#`).

Comment: Note: `[\'|\"]` matches `'`, `|` or `"`. I think you meant `[\'\"]`, which can be simplified to `['"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes cause Bash to  replace variable references like `$1` and `$2` with the values of these shell variables. Use single quotes around your Perl script to avoid this (or quote every  dollar sign, backtick, etc in the script).

However, you cannot escape  single quotes inside single quotes easily; a common workaround in Perl strings is to use the character code `\x27` instead.  If you need single-quoted Perl strings, use the generalized single-quoting operator `q{...}`.

If you need to interpolate a shell variable name, a common trick is to use "see-saw" quoting.  The string `'str'"in"'g'` in the shell is equal to `'string'` after quote removal; you can similarly use adjacent single-quoted and double-quoted strings to build your script ... although it does tend to get rather unreadable.

```
perl -nle 'print "Instance -> $1\nRevision -> $2"
  while /^(?!#)('"$NAME"'_.+rev).+[\x27"]([^\x27"]*)[\x27"]$/g' non-hadoop.en
```

(Notice that the options `-nle` are not part of the script; the script is the quoted argument to the `-e` option.  In fact `perl '-nle script ...'` coincidentally works, but it is decidedly unidiomatic, to the point of confusing.)

Comment: I need to include a variable in this now but it doesn't seem to work.  Usually in perl I would just do something like this ${variable} but it seems like the current command is calling the literal name  `perl '-nle print "Instance -> $1\nRevision -> $2" while /^(?!#)($NAME_.+rev).+[\x27"]([^\x27"]*)[\x27"]$/g;' non-hadoop.env`

Comment: Don't generate code, especially not in a shell script. Instead, pass the value as argument or as an env var.

Answer (score 3):

Using single quotes around your arguments to prevent special processing of `$`, `\`, etc. If you need to include a single quote within, the generic solution is to use `'\''`. In this particular case, however, we can avoid trying to include a `'` by using the equivalent `\x27` in the regex pattern instead.

```
perl -nle'
   print "$1 => $2"
      while /^(?!#)(loop_.+rev).+?[\x27\"|](.+?)[\x27\"|]$/g;
' non-hadoop.env
```

[I added some line breaks for readability. You can actually leave them in if you want to, but you don't need to.]

---

Note that there are some problems with your regex pattern.

1. `(?!\#)(loop_.+rev)` is the same as `(loop_.+rev)` since `l` isn't `#`, so `(?!\#)` isn't doing whatever you think it's doing.
2. `[\'|\"]` matches `'`, `"` and `|`, but I think you only meant it to match `'` and `"`. If so, you want to use `[\'\"]`, which can be simplified to `['"]`.
3. Don't use the non-greedy modifier (`?` after `+`, `*`, etc). It's used for optimization, not for excluding characters. In fact, the second `?` in your pattern has absolutely no effect, so it's not doing what you think it's doing.

Fixed?

```
perl -nle'
   print "$1 => $2"
      while /^(loop_.+rev).+[\x27"]([^\x27"]*)[\x27"]$/g;
' non-hadoop.env
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out due to all of you guys help.  Thanks again.  Here is my final command

```
perl -nle 'print "$1 $2" while /^($ENV{NAME}_.+rev).+\x27(.+)\x27/g;' $ENVFILE
```

Comment: Then please mark one of the answers as accepted; your own if you like.  This prevents this question from coming up as unanswered.